# Is Entity Framework 'Packages' folder needed for production?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dll, webforms

I have a webforms projects with entity framework 5 and .NET 4.5. When I'm publishing the the web site it generates 'packages' directory in the compiled code, with some entity framework dll's in it. However  the website functions well even If I remove it. It should be mentioned that I don't use code-first.
What is the purpose of this folder?

TIA.

Comment: What version of .net framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're using `EF5`, as version `5.0`, not the `4.4` that may happen if you first installed the `EF5` on `.net 4` and updated to `.net 4.5` later.

http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/when-entity-framework-5-ef5-is-not-entity-framework-5-ef5/

From `EF5` on, entity framework is a separate api(package) that can be installed via `Library Package Manager` or `NuGet` from `Visual Studio`, it is not part of `.net framework` installation any more.

`packages` folder is a default one for `NuGet` package installation.

So, please have a look at the `EntityFramework` reference that must be present in your project where you actually work with EF, and see the version and the location of assembly you are referencing. If your `Copy Local` property is set to true, you don't need to include `packages` folder in your installation package, assembly will be copied to `bin` folder automatically, otherwise you'll have to.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is : No, you don't need the packages folder

Long answer : No, you don't need the packages folder in production, its created by nuget when you install a package to hold the dlls for that package.

So if you include EF in your project it will be copied in there and a reference will be added to your project to ~/packages/Entityframework.dll, at compile time a copy of the dll will be put in your bin folder.

During releases to our live environment I routinely remove this folder as its not needed.